# Dynamically adding required to input in template driven angular 2 form

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

**Template driven approach:** Dynamically adding required attribute to input filed in angular 2 form. But the angular form validation(form.valid) not recognizing the dynamically added required field.

```
 <input type="text"  [(ngModel)]="coumnName" name="coumnName" >
```

Adding dynamically required:

```
document.getElementsByName(columnName)[0].setAttribute('required', '');
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the same technique as setting a validator dynamically for a `FormControl` in a reactive form, but using the `NgForm` directive. How come? What angular actually does with the `NgForm` directive it creates `FormControl` instances registered to the `name` you assign in your form.

So what you can do, is import `NgForm`, `Validators` and `ViewChild` to reference your form and be able to use it in your component. As a side note, I see that your `ngModel` variable is the same as the `name` attribute. That won't work, they need to be unique.

So do the following:

```html
<form #f="ngForm">
  <input [(ngModel)]="coumnNameModel" name="coumnName" #coumnName="ngModel">
</form>
```

and in your component, import `NgForm` and `ViewChild` and then use `setValidators()` and set whatever validators you want, then call `updateValueAndValidity()`:

```ts
@ViewChild('f') myForm: NgForm;

// when you want to set required validator:
setRequired() {
  this.myForm.form.get('coumnName').setValidators([Validators.required])
  this.myForm.form.get('coumnName').updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

### [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mvgjtg?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Newer versions of angular require two parameters for ViewChild.  See: `@ViewChild('f', {static:false}) myForm: NgForm;`

Answer (score 2):

> In fact, once you start data binding, you are no longer working with HTML attributes. You aren't setting attributes. You are setting the properties of DOM elements, components, and directives.

You can read this [official doc](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#html-attribute-vs-dom-property)

Answer (score 1):

Just need to add:

```
[required]="isConditionIsTrue"
```

in your input.

You can use a condition or a boolean.

**NOTE: if you are using formControls you shoul**d:

add the required control, or any other control:

```
this.form.addControl('formControlName', new FormControl(ValueToSet, Validators.required));
```

and if you want to remove the required control, or any other control:

```
this.form.get('formControlName').reset();
this.form.removeControl('formControlName');
```

Comment: This doesn't work. When the condition returns false, the validity of the form is not recalculated and you cannot submit the form.

Comment: Ciao Emanuele, if you are using formControls you should:

add the required control:

this.form.addControl('formControlName', new FormControl(ValueToSet, Validators.required));

and if you want to remove it:

        this.form.get('formControlName').reset();
        this.form.removeControl('formControlName');

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes with reactive form this works that way. 
Anyway it seems that is needed to add and remove validators with code behind also with template driven forms.
In your example, once the isConditionIsTrue became true, the required validator stay active even if isConditionITrue  change back to false.