# Angular setValidators(Validators.required) not changing empty control to be invalid

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms, required, formarray

I created a Reactive Form on Angular 6.
Inside the form, I have a nested FormArray. 
On the HTML side I initialize the inputs array using *ngFor directive.

Above the FormArray, I have a checkBox formControl.
I want the checkBox value to set/remove the Validators.required respectively.

Note that all of the inputs inside the array of controls, need to be updated by the checkbox changes.

See below how I achieve that.

On checking/unchecking the checkbox, the inputs created by the *ngFor directive supposed to get red on case they are empty - since their validators were updated to include the "required" validator.

But, the problem is, it seems "setValidators(Validators.required)" does not make any change to the controls. The control status remains VALID altought it is empty while required.

ts side:

```
get UnitFirstMeter() {
return this.configReportForm.get('unitsFirstMeters');
```

}

ngOnInit(): void {

```
this.configReportForm = this._fb.group({
  reportType: [''],
  reportPeriod: [],
  firstReport: [false],
  unitsFirstMeters: this._fb.array(this.unitsForReport)
});


this.configReportForm.get('firstReport').valueChanges.subscribe(checkedValue => {
  const unitsFirstMeters = this.configReportForm.get('unitsFirstMeters');
  console.log(checkedValue);
  console.log((unitsFirstMeters as FormArray).controls);
  if (checkedValue) {
    (unitsFirstMeters as FormArray).controls.forEach(c => {
      c.setValidators(Validators.required);
      console.log(c.status);
    })
  } else {
    (unitsFirstMeters as FormArray).controls.forEach(c => {
      c.clearValidators();
      console.log(c.status);
    });
  }
  (unitsFirstMeters as FormArray).controls.forEach(c => {
    c.updateValueAndValidity();
  });
});
```

}

HTML side:

```
<form class="text-right myFont" [formGroup]="configReportForm">
    <div class="form-group ">
        <label>Rport Type</label>
        <select class="form-control" style="direction:rtl" formControlName="reportType">
            <option value="" style="direction:rtl">בחר את סוג הדו"ח</option>
            <option value="{{type.typeId}}" style="direction:rtl" *ngFor="let type of reportTypes">{{type.typeName}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Report month and year</label>
        <input type="month" class="form-control" formControlName="reportPeriod">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
            <label>This is my first report</label>
            <input type="checkbox" formControlName="firstReport" class="ml-2 mt-1">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div formArrayName="unitsFirstMeters">

        <div *ngFor="let unit of unitsForReport; let i = index" class="form-group form-row" >
            <input type="number" class="col-9 text-right form-control" formControlName="{{i}}"
            [class.is-invalid]="UnitFirstMeter.at(i).invalid">
            <label class="col-3 col-form-label">{{unit.unitName}}</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn myFont btn-warning" type="submit">Create</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically adding required to input in template driven angular 2 form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48645671/dynamically-adding-required-to-input-in-template-driven-angular-2-form)

Comment: Could you provide a https://stackblitz.com minimum reproduction? Posting the code as you did is great. Adding a link to a reproduction demo is even greater.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale  - the question you've reffered me to shows how to update a single input "required" property. Maybe you can show me how to achieve that on an array of inputs? when I run 
const unitsFirstMeters = this.myForm.form.get('unitFirstMeter'); I get a single form control, altough there are 4 inputs with the name unitFirstMeter. (the 4 inputs are represented as an array of objects inside the value propery of the returned formControl)

Comment: @tovale is that working for single Control?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale - I've checked and it does not work with single Control as well. Looks like the issue is with the setValidators(Validators.required);

Comment: @tovale it should be `setValidators([Validators.required])` not `setValidators(Validators.required);`

Comment: the parameter accepts array!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale - It does not worl also as I pass it an array.

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz?>